# Show relation is bijective

Tags: functions, solution-verification

Let $f:A\mapsto B$, and $g:B \mapsto C$ be two bijective relations. Show that $g \circ f:A \mapsto C$ is also bijective.

Proof : As I understand it, the relation $g \circ f:A \mapsto C$ takes an element from the domain of $f$ and pairs it with an element from the codomain of $g$, such that a pair $(a\in A,c \in C)$ is formed. For $g \circ f$ to be bijective, we have to show both injectivity and surjectivity. If the composite relation is injective, that means $$(a_1,c)\in g\circ f=(a_2,c)\in g\circ f \rightarrow a_1=a_2$$

must be true. Assuming the contradiction, that is $$a_1 \neq a_2$$

However, this means we have two pairs $(a_1,b)$ and $(a_2,b)$ in the set $f \subset A \times B$. This contradicts the fact that $f$ is bijective, and thus $g \circ f$ is injective.

Now, every pair $(a,c)$ in $g \circ f$ is an element of $A \times C$ only if $aRb$ and $bRc$. Since $f$ and $g$ are both bijective, this means we can always  find $a \in A$ for every $c \in C$ such that $aRc$. Thus $g \circ f$ is surjective and therefore a bijective relation. What are the flaws in this proof?

Comment: "Now, every pair $(a,c)$ in $g\circ f$ is an element of $A\times C$ **if** and only if **there exists a $b$ such that** $aRb$ and $bRc$"  You had neglected to define $b$ here.

Comment: Right, but certainly such a b must always exist since f and g are bijective - I'll be sure to add that to the proof.

Comment: Why is $g\circ f$ **equal** to $(a_2,c)$?

Comment: The wording is awkward. It should read, that the pairs are equal to each other AND they are both from the set $g \circ f$